# Not able to save an edit after making changes to the input element in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I'm making changes to an `<input>` content. I'm able to see the changes that I make with the help of `<pre></pre>` but when I clicked on `Save Edit` button, the changes were not reflecting on the UI. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

This was the function for saving the edit ( [Source code](https://github.com/pavanchilukuri/classifieds-listing-app/tree/master/components/classifieds/edit) )

```
function saveEdit() {
  vm.sidenavOpen = false;
  $scope.$emit('editSaved', 'Edit Saved!');
}
```

I was getting the below exception when I debugged on browser.

```
TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)
    at Object.saveEdit (http://localhost:8080/components/classifieds/edit/classifieds.edit.ctr.js:36:17)
    at fn (eval at compile (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:15551:15), <anonymous>:4:164)
    at callback (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:27341:17)
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:18423:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:18523:25)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:27346:23)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:3771:11)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:3759:9)
```

Comment: Your source code doesn't appear to have any dependency injections.

Comment: @rrd That link which i provided is for just edit functionality. Please see the root for that repo.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] in the question itself if you want help ... not links to a repo that will change over time